# Removing Excessive Loops

Tags: python

This is a very basic program. It stores the student data and then displays the student name with the highest marks.
Ignoring the time complexity for my code, how can I format my code in such a way that it uses less while loops.

```
student_names, test_1, test_2, test_3, total_score = [], [], [], [], []

i = 0
while i < 30:
    student = input("Student: ").title()
    student_names.append(student)
    while True:
        test1 = int(input("Test-1 score: "))
        if 0 <= test1 <= 20:
            test_1.append(test1)
            break
        else:
            print("Range Error for Test1 Score :( ")

    while True:
        test2 = int(input("Test-2 score: "))
        if 0 <= test2 <= 25:
            test_2.append(test2)
            break
        else:
            print("Range Error for Test2 Score :( ")

    while True:
        test3 = int(input("Test-3 score: "))
        if 0 <= test3 <= 35:
            test_3.append(test3)
            print('')
            break
        else:
            print("Range Error for Test3 Score :( ")

    total = test_1[i] + test_2[i] + test_3[i]
    total_score.append(total)

    max_score = total_score[0]
    if total_score[i] > max_score:
        max_score = total_score[i]
    i += 1

avg_score = 0
for i in range(30):
    avg_score += total_score[i]

print(f"Average Score: {avg_score/3}")
print(f"{student_names[total_score.index(max_score)]} scored Highest of {max_score}/{35+25+20}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the duplicated input validation code.

```
def input_int(name, max_score):
    while True:
        x = int(input(name))
        if 0 <= x <= max_score:
            return x
        else:
            print('Range error for %s :(' % name)
```

and then in your code:

```
 test_1.append(input_int('Test 1 Score', 20))
 test_2.append(input_int('Test 2 Score', 25))
 test_3.append(input_int('Test 3 Score', 35))
```